# Spring Cloud Config & Bus track only one branch

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I have a Git repository with 2 branches(main, local), Spring Cloud Config Server(with spring cloud bus), and Spring App (client for config).

I want the config server to track changes only on the local branch. I've tried to specify the label in cloud config properties, but this label probably indicates only which branch should be used, when properties are requested without specifying the label.

How it works right now:

- Property file changed in git
- Git sends the webhook request to my config server
- /monitor endpoint receives it, and publishes the message to a topic, no matter what branch was affected(probably it's not possible to change)
- Client app receives the message and tries to resolve whether this message was addressed to him and whether he should refresh its context

And here is the problem: the message doesn't contain information about an affected branch, so my client always trying to refresh the context and requests new properties from the config server, even if they didn't change.

In the end, I want to make a branch per environment(profile). Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, nothing really available to do that right now. You might be able to write an interceptor around the monitor endpoint and inspect the contents and like for the right branch and only proceed if it is local.